# iOS Home app notification sound

Tags: ios, audio, homekit

Is there a way to change the sounds for notifications from a HomeKit device? I have a flood device and want to make sure I don't overlook a notice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot change the notification sound unless the app supports it (or it is one of the notification types listed under Settings > Sounds & Haptics), which Home does not (and it is not).